# How to add button to annotation view in XCode(iOS SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk

In `MKAnnotation` there are just title and subtitle, and i don't add anything control to annotation. How to I add a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using following delegate method of Map View. You can set right call out accessory view as button

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

MKAnnotationView *view = nil; 
//MKPinAnnotationView *view=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"HotSpotsLoc"];

if(annotation !=mapView.userLocation){
    view = (MKAnnotationView *) 
    [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"]; 
    if(nil == view) { 
        view = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] 
                 initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"] 
                autorelease];           
    }


    ParkPlaceMark *currPlaceMark = annotation;
    NSLog(@"%i",currPlaceMark.position);

        view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];

    UIButton *btnViewVenue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView=btnViewVenue;
    view.enabled = YES;
    view.canShowCallout = YES;
    view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    //view.animatesDrop = YES;

}       
return view;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**  Disregard this answer.  Your complete question was not being shown because of bad markup and I extrapolated (incorrectly) what your question was.

---

You can drag anything onto the `UITableViewCell` you want to from the objects palette at right.

If you want to add it as the `accessoryView` however, do **not** do that.
Add it to the interface file as a separate top level object and drag a connection from the `accessoryView` outlet of the cell to the view/button you want.

Comment: thanks, i will after my edit of the question is accepted - so that others will know that there's an issue