# Increase size of annotationview display

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, mkmapview

I am using MKMapKit. Initially it has just a title and a subtitle. But when user drags pin and set to new location it has title with one button "save". I have done this but when I add button to annotationview it is not displaying because of space. 
[image]

[image]

Button is shown by three dots.

Comment: helpful link more describes how to add button annotation view [duplicates][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550201/how-to-add-button-to-annotation-view-in-xcodeios-sdk

Comment: post the codez for your custom annotation

Answer (score 0):

This is the callout view we cannot change its size if you change the size of this you have to use custom callout UIView.

Comment: You can check it on google & search how to add custom callout view.